# PHP Error of Integrating Discord (Xenforo)

Tags: php, xenforo

When I enable the addons of Xenforo, it shows this. My server in another host with SAME php version can make this with no error. So it is not the plugin problem.

```
An exception occurred: Undefined index: instant_invite in 
/home/blackfor/public_html/library/EWRdiscord/Listener/NavTabs.php on line 17  
XenForo_Application::handlePhpError() in EWRdiscord/Listener/NavTabs.php at line 17
EWRdiscord_Listener_NavTabs::listen() call_user_func_array() in XenForo/CodeEvent.php at line 90
XenForo_CodeEvent::fire() in XenForo/Dependencies/Public.php at line 495
XenForo_Dependencies_Public->_getNavigationContainerParams() in 
XenForo/Dependencies/Public.php at line 371
XenForo_Dependencies_Public->getEffectiveContainerParams() in 
XenForo/FrontController.php at line 637
XenForo_FrontController->renderView() in XenForo/FrontController.php at line 158
XenForo_FrontController->run() in /home/blackfor/public_html/index.php at line 13
```

ScreenShots

[image]

I am currently using [8WAYRUN] Discord Integration addon for Xenforo.

Comment: It would help to show the code that gives the error so. It seems pretty clear what the error is, but no way to anyone to help you by not reviewing code snippets where the issue lies.

Comment: I am so bad at finding bugs, just a new starter I mean. And I thought it is not the file problem. I think it is the host problem at the first. Because I host the same file on two different server. But one works and one doesn't.

Comment: NavTabs.php ? I wonder is it

Comment: Are you using an add-on? Because it could help narrow down the issues.

Comment: This clearly is issue with the addon and not related to your server, Have you checked the database tables to make sure they are correct?